# Ganache Smart Contract

Tags: ganache, web3.py

is it possible to use a smart contract of an existing token in ganache for testing ?? that is, I don't have to create my smart contract

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check the Tuffle Box for that.

Comment: Could you help me or give me a reference I am new to the use of the blockchain and I only used ganache to make queries and test transactions.